# Why is $(\sqrt{P})^2=P$ where $P$ is a positive operator on a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

The following is a proposition regarding positive operators on a Hilbert space in Douglas's *Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator Theory*:

[image]

Corollary 4.32 is as the following:
[image]

I understand that the (continuous) functional calculus is defined as the following:

[image]

Here is my **question**:

> How is it true that $(\sqrt{P})^2=P$ by the definition of the functional calculus?

Comment: By the definition of the Functional Calculus, $(fg)(P)=f(P)g(P)$ and $g(P)=P$ if $g(x)=x$.

Comment: Exactly. The Gelfand map is an isomorphism which implies that it has the property that TrialAndError has stated.